# Angular2 application not updating upon event emit

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a child component that is used to update a phone number on the page.  When the user hits the 'save' button, the application is supposed to get the text of the changed phone number then automatically update the phone number that is seen in the application.

Application view
[image]

Popup allowing the user to change the phone number
[image]

So when the user hits the save button on the popup, the number in the application needs to change automatically.  However, this isn't happening.  The number isn't changing until I do a hard refresh on the page.  Can anyone explain to me what I need to do to fix this?

**editPhone.component(Popup)**

```
@Output() phoneChanged = new EventEmitter<string>();
constructor(private _http: HttpClient, private _phone: PhoneService){}
//Is called when the user clicks the 'Save' button

    savePhone(patientOrder: PatientOrder, phoneText: string){
            this._phone.patientId = patientOrder.patientId;

            return this._http.post('service', this._phone).subscribe((result:any) => {
                this._phone.phoneText = result.phoneNumber;
                this.phoneChanged.emit(this._phone.phoneText);
            });
        }
```

**view.component(Application where the phone should be seen updating)**

```
 phoneNumber: string = "";
    phoneChanged(phone: string){
    //I'm never getting to this point.  The application isn't failing, I'm just never seeing this being logged.
            console.log(phone);
        }
```

**view.html(Template)**

```
<new-orders>
<div (phoneChanged)="phoneChanged($event)">{{phoneNumber}}</div>
</new-orders>
```

To keep from having comments and questions asked whether I have the application set up properly, whether or not I'm hitting my service, etc, know that everything works the way it should except this part of the application

Comment: It feels like `editPhone.component` is not child of `view.component`, but hard to guess from this code.

Answer (score 1):

that div isn't the edit phone component, so it's not outputting the event you're trying to bind to.  Really I'm surprised this doesn't throw an error when you compile.

you would need to do it like:

```
<edit-phone (phoneChanged)="phoneChanged($event)"></edit-phone>
```

so you bind to the event on the component that emits the event.  But this only works if the edit-phone is a direct child of the component where you display the phone number, if it's a sibling or cousin or something, you need to use a shared service pattern instead.

Answer (score 0):

From code you provided `view.component` is not parent of `editPhone.component`. Which means it can't listen for `@output`.

Working html would looks like:

```
   <view-component>
    // Some MARKUP here
    <edit-phone-component (phoneChanged)="phoneChanged($event)"></edit-phone-component>
   </view-component>
```

Also you will probably need to give eidt component `@Input()` with current value

So final code may looks like:

```
  <view-component>
    // Some MARKUP here
    <edit-phone-component 
    [phoneNumber]=phoneNumber
    (phoneChanged)="phoneChanged($event)"></edit-phone-component>
   </view-component>
```

and editPhoneComponent

```
export class EditPhoneComponent {
    @Input() phoneNumber: string;
    @Output() phoneChanged = new EventEmitter<string>();

    // Other method and constructor comes here

    savePhone(patientOrder: PatientOrder, phoneText: string){
      // Some logic for saving comes here
      this.phoneChanged.emit(this._phone.phoneText);
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue is that he's binding to the event on the div where he's displaying the phone number rather than on the component outputting the event.  It's unclear if the edit component is a child of the view or not.